# What is mean file:workspaces in package dependencies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules

I try use npm 7 workspaces

```
"workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "packages/apps/*",
      "packages/components",
    ],
```

and after install I see in my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@project/components": "file:workspaces/components",
```

Is it correct ? And what is mean file: ?

Comment: https://github.com/ruanmartinelli/npm-workspaces-demo
Check out this demo.I think this would clear your doubts

Answer (score 1):

**Workspaces** is a generic term that refers to the set of features in the npm CLI that provides support to managing multiple packages from your local files system from within a singular top-level, root package.

[For more details](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces)

**Defining workspaces**

Workspaces are usually defined via the workspaces property of the package.json file, e.g:

```
{
  "name": "my-workspaces-powered-project",
  "workspaces": [
    "workspace-a"
  ]
}
```

Given the above `package.json` example living at a current working directory `.` that contains a folder named `workspace-a` that itself contains a `package.json` inside it, defining a Node.js package, e.g:

```
.
+-- package.json
`-- workspace-a
   `-- package.json
```